# I want to check whether one week is over with jodatime

Tags: java, android, date, jodatime

I tried to check whether one week is over with `from.isBefore(to)`. from is LocalDate (e.g. today) and to is `from.plusDays(6)`, So one week. Now the issue is that it is always true. How can I fix the `toDate`, that the `fromDate` is just counting and after reach do something in the if-condition?

```
LocalDate from = LocalDate.now();

LocalDate to = from.withPeriodAdded(Period.days(6), 1);

if(from.isBefore(to)) {
   //do something;
}....
```

Comment: I think you need to specify when that week began. And then compare `to` to today.

Comment: This question is unclear; voting to close. Asking if today is within a week is silly, obviously today is always within a week. Rewrite to explain exactly what you want. Do you want to know if today is contained within a particular date range? That has been covered many times already, so search before posting.

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: FYI, the troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The current week obviously isn’t over, so I don’t think that this was what you meant. I am struggling to understand what you meant instead. Maybe you want to give an example of when one week is over and another example of when it isn’t, for clarity, please? I have voted to close as unclear and am looking forward to retracting my close vote once you’ve clarified.

Comment: Ok, I send an apicall and write the results into files. But next Tuesday for example I don't want this result I want a new apicall. Is this understandable? 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it.
I write the current LocalDate in my daily-files.
Then I read the String with index.Of out of the File and parse it into LocalDate. I add to this Date 6 Days and counter from CurrentDate.
Maybe this is not the best solution but it works...

```
    //In my Async-Class where the Files get written
          LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
          outputStream.write(currentDate.toString().getBytes());


 //In my Main-clasS
    final LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now(); //Current Date
    final int daysbetween = 6; //days between current date and date of file
    final int index = openfilewed().indexOf("2", 30); //Date from file
    final LocalDate[] filedate = new LocalDate[1];
    final LocalDate[] reach = new LocalDate[1];

     filedate[0] = LocalDate.parse(openfilemon().substring(index));
     reach[0] = filedate[0].plusDays(daysbetween);
           if (currentDate.isBefore(reach[0])){
              //do something
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `from`, and you you calculate `to` by adding 6 days to `from`, `from` will **always** be before to (and `from.isBefore(to)` will always return `True`). You need to explicitely check whether the difference between two dates is 7 days.

Take a look at static the `daysBetween(ReadableInstant start,                             ReadableInstant end)` method.